# Laravel 5.1 access event object in listener

Tags: laravel, events, queue, listeners

I am trying out Laravel 5.1's queue, I am having a problem working with $event object in its listener.

AuthController.php

```
public function postGenerateResetToken()
{
    try
    {
        $admin = Admin::where( 'email', '=', Input::get( 'email' ) )->firstOrFail();

        $token = Bus::dispatch( new GeneratePasswordResetToken( $admin ) );

        event( new PasswordResetTokenWasGenerated( $admin, $token ) );

        return success();
    }
    catch( ModelNotFoundException $exception )
    {
        return fail();
    }
}
```

PasswordResetTokenWasGenerated.php

```
class PasswordResetTokenWasGenerated extends Event
{

    use SerializesModels;

    public function __construct( $admin, $token )
    {
        $this->admin = $admin;
        $this->token = $token;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

SendForgottenPasswordEmail.php

```
class SendForgottenPasswordEmail implements ShouldQueue
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function handle(PasswordResetTokenWasGenerated $event)
    {
        $data = [
            'admin' => $event->admin,
            'token' => $event->token
        ];

        Mail::send( 'emails.forgotten-password', $data, function( $message ) use ( $event )
        {
            $message->subject( 'Forgotten password' );

            $message->to( $event->admin->email );
        });
    }
}
```

Using `$event->admin` in handler results in `Undefined property: PasswordResetTokenWasGenerated::$admin`

But, this error only occurs when I implement `ShouldQueue` interface on Listener. It works just fine without the interface.

The queue driver is set to `sync`.

I know this is because of the queue, but isn't it supposed to work the way I want it to work?

Comment: Could you paste the real code of the event class? What you provided is some pseud-code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare your admin and token as public before setting them:

class PasswordResetTokenWasGenerated extends Event
{

```
use SerializesModels;

public $admin;
public $token;

public function __construct( $admin, $token )
{
    $this->admin = $admin;
    $this->token = $token;
}

public function broadcastOn()
{
    return [];
}
```

}

After that you should be able to access those properties in your Listener.

Comment: Amazing! This actually fixed the issue. I wouldn't discover this as 'public' is the default access modifier... But, of course, how would reflection work... Thank you!